# i want to add 2 scroller in one flutter screen

Tags: flutter

i have one screen where i want to scroll the entire page and there is a comment section on the same page i want to scroll that list of comments independently.i tried and with this code only main page is scrolling but not comment list. how to do it?

this is my main page code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:quix_note/src/base/data.dart';
import 'package:quix_note/src/models/comment/comment_model.dart';
import 'package:quix_note/src/models/comment/comment_response_model.dart';
import 'package:quix_note/src/models/note/note_model.dart';
import 'package:quix_note/src/service/api/comment_api_config.dart';
import 'package:quix_note/src/utils/app_colors.dart';
import 'package:quix_note/src/widgets/app_textfield.dart';
import '../../base/nav.dart';
import '../../utils/error_dialog.dart';
import '../../widgets/no_data.dart';

class NoteDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  const NoteDetail({Key? key, required this.noteModel}) : super(key: key);
  final NoteModel noteModel;

  @override
  State<NoteDetail> createState() => _NoteDetailState();
}

class _NoteDetailState extends State<NoteDetail> {
  //controllers
  final _commentController = TextEditingController();
  final api = CommentApiConfig();

  void postComment() async {
    try {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      );
      final commentModel = CommentModel(
          userId: AppData.loggedUserId,
          noteId: widget.noteModel.id!,
          comment: _commentController.text);
      await api.postComment(commentModel: commentModel);
      await api.getAllCommentByNoteId(noteId: widget.noteModel.id!);
      if (!mounted) return;

      Navigator.pop(context);
      // AppNavigation.pop();
    } catch (e) {
      ErrorDialog(
        error: e,
      ).show(context);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back_ios,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'Note detail',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                fontSize: 18,
              ),
        ),
        actions: [
          PopupMenuButton<int>(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.more_horiz,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            itemBuilder: (context) => [
              PopupMenuItem(
                value: 1,
                child: Text(
                  "Share",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                        fontSize: 15,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      ),
                ),
              ),
              PopupMenuItem(
                value: 2,
                // row has two child icon and text
                child: Text(
                  "Delete",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                        fontSize: 15,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
            offset: const Offset(10, 20),
            color: Colors.white,
            elevation: 2,
            surfaceTintColor: Colors.white,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 29, vertical: 10),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                Text(
                  widget.noteModel.priority.toString(),
                  style: textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                    color: AppColors.primaryYellow,
                    fontSize: 14,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 5),
                Text(
                  widget.noteModel.title.toString(),
                  style: textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                    color: AppColors.darkTeal,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    const Card(
                        elevation: 5,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.calendar_month_sharp,
                            color: AppColors.primaryYellow,
                          ),
                        )),
                    const SizedBox(width: 2),
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Deadline',
                          style: textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                            fontSize: 14,
                            color: AppColors.darkGrey,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          DateFormat('E, d MMMM')
                              .format(widget.noteModel.deadline!)
                              .toString(),
                          style: textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                Text(
                  'My Todo',
                  style: textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                    color: AppColors.darkTeal,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                Text(
                  widget.noteModel.description.toString(),
                  style: textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                    color: AppColors.darkGrey,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    fontSize: 16,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                if (widget.noteModel.media != "null")
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Media',
                        style: textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                          color: AppColors.darkTeal,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          fontSize: 20,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 20),
                      if (widget.noteModel.media?.isNotEmpty ?? false) ...[
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 200,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                width: 2.0,
                              ),
                              color: Colors.black,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            ),
                            child: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                              child: Image.network(
                                widget.noteModel.media ?? '',
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                loadingBuilder: (_, child, loadingProgress) {
                                  if (loadingProgress == null) {
                                    return child;
                                  }
                                  return Container(
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    child: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                  );
                                },
                              ), // Your image widget goes here
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ] else ...[
                        const Center(child: Text('No Media Available!')),
                      ],
                    ],
                  ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                Text(
                  'VA Comments',
                  style: textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                    color: AppColors.darkTeal,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    fontSize: 22,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                AppTextField(
                  maxLines: 1,
                  textEditingController: _commentController,
                  // textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty || value.trim().isEmpty) {
                      return 'Comment Text is required.';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  hint: 'Comment',
                  suffix: IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.attachment_outlined),
                    onPressed: postComment,
                  ),
                  fillColor: const Color(0xffefefef),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                CommentItem(noteId: widget.noteModel.id!),
                // const SizedBox(height: 10),
                // const CommentItem(),
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is my comment section

```
class CommentItem extends StatefulWidget {
  const CommentItem({Key? key, required this.noteId}) : super(key: key);

  final String noteId;

  @override
  State<CommentItem> createState() => _CommentItemState();
}

class _CommentItemState extends State<CommentItem> {
  final api = CommentApiConfig();
  var isLoading = true;
  var commentResponseModel = <CommentResponseModel>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAllComments();
  }

  void getAllComments() async {
    try {
      commentResponseModel =
          await api.getAllCommentByNoteId(noteId: widget.noteId);
    } catch (e) {
      ErrorDialog(error: e).show(context);
    }
    isLoading = false;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;
    return isLoading
        ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
        : SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: commentResponseModel.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      const CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 25,
                        foregroundColor: AppColors.primaryYellow,
                        child: Icon(Icons.person),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            commentResponseModel[index].fullName,
                            style: textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                              fontSize: 14,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              color: AppColors.darkGrey,
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(width: 5),
                          Text(
                            commentResponseModel[index].comment,
                            style: textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                              fontSize: 12,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              color: AppColors.darkGrey,
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const Divider(
                    height: 10,
                    thickness: 1,
                    indent: 10,
                    endIndent: 10,
                    color: AppColors.dividerGrey,
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing the Minimum Viable code, where the inside scroll & the outside scroll are separated. It can work in many ways. I am showing you in 2 different ways in the below-mentioned source code. Feel free to provide acknowledgement in the comment section.

One way using `SingleChildScrollView`:

```
Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(height: 200, color: Colors.orange),
        Container(height: 200, color: Colors.blue),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 100,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(title: Text("Inner 00")),
                ListTile(title: Text("Inner 01")),
                ListTile(title: Text("Inner 02")),
                ListTile(title: Text("Inner 03")),
                ListTile(title: Text("Inner 04")),
                ListTile(title: Text("Inner 05")),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(height: 200, color: Colors.green),
        Container(height: 200, color: Colors.purple),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Another way using `ListView`:

```
Scaffold(
  body: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(height: 200, color: Colors.orange),
          Container(height: 200, color: Colors.blue),
          SizedBox(
            height: 100,
            child: ListView(
              children: const <Widget>[
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(title: Text("Inner 00")),
                    ListTile(title: Text("Inner 01")),
                    ListTile(title: Text("Inner 02")),
                    ListTile(title: Text("Inner 03")),
                    ListTile(title: Text("Inner 04")),
                    ListTile(title: Text("Inner 05")),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(height: 200, color: Colors.green),
          Container(height: 200, color: Colors.purple),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

It works when SingleChildScrollView is in the base & ListView is in the sub or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass height size for CommentItem and set shinkWrap = false;

ScrollView needs height to measure the scope of the scroll.

if shinkWrap = true the child scroll will use the size of it's parent.